# How to change laravel validation error message

Tags: laravel

I know laravel provides customisable error messages for each validation rules but is there a way to change the `message` part of the json result? I can't seem to find anything on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you validate it?

Comment: just using the `FormRequest` an placing the validation rules inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely create your own Exception class and instruct laravel to use it to reply the response.

Assuming your own custom Exception class is `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException` you only need to override `failedValidation` method in your form request class and have something like this.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

...

/**
 * @param Validator $validator
 * @throws HttpResponseException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        response()->json(
            [
                'message' => 'My message',
                'errors' => $validator->errors()->get('*') //or ->all() instead of get()
            ],
            Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
        )
    );
}
```

The above would ensure your custom error response format is used. You can also add it to a Trait and include it in all your request class or just create a base Request class that others should extend.

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but... could you possibly show how to instruct Laravel to use the custom exception instead of its built-in one?

Comment: By design, declaring this in your form request will overwrite failedValidation method inherited by the form request which means a failed response would come out based on your definition. If you mean to instruct Laravel to throw your custom exception instead of all Laravel built in, then maybe you want to look into Handler.php and intercept in-built exception before they reach your users. Generally look for topics such as error handling in Laravel.

Comment: Ah! I missed `in your form request class` in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add custom message on your venue class as follow:

```
public static function messages($id = '') {
return [
    'name.required' => 'You must enter your name',
    'logo.required' => 'You must upload logo',
    'key.rules' => 'your messages'
];
```

And on your controller add messages as third parameter.

```
$this->validate($request, Venue::rules(), Venue::messages());
```

Answer (score 1):

The “The given data was invalid.” message is actually the exception class message, which isn’t easily configurable:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php#L46-L56

Comment: That's too bad. Is there a way to create my own exception and get laravel to throw the custom exception instead of `ValidationException`? That way i can just copy the existing features and add in my own custom ones.